# Borrar un departamento y si tienen personas asociadas meterlas en otro

Tags: java, sql

Baja de Departamentos, solo se podrá borrar un departamento si no existe ninguna persona asociada, o bien, asignarla a otro departamento "ficticio")

esta  es mi idea pero no se si esta bien.
un select para saber si tengo o no personas en el departamento si tengo las cambio a otro que creo y borro el departamento

si no tengo presonas lo borro del tiron

```
   public boolean borrarDepartamento(Departamento d, int numDepartamento) {
    boolean flag = false;
    boolean existe = false;
    String nombreD = d.getNombre();
    String direccion = d.getDireccion();
    int numNDepartamento = d.getNumDepartamento();
    try {
        Statement orden = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet res;
        res = orden.executeQuery("SELECT count(nombrePersona) FROM persona WHERE numDepartamento ='" + numDepartamento);
        if (res.next()) {
            existe = (res.getInt("total") > 0);
        }
        if (existe == true) {
            Statement orden1 = conn.createStatement();
            orden1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO departamento(nombre, direccion, numDepto)  VALUES('"
                    + nombreD + "','" + direccion + "','" + numNDepartamento + "')");
            orden1.close();
            Statement orden2 = conn.createStatement();
            orden2.executeUpdate("UPDATE persona "
                    + "SET numDepto = '" + numDepartamento + "',"
                    + "WHERE numDepartamento = " + numNDepartamento);
            orden2.close();
            Statement orden3 = conn.createStatement();
            orden3.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM departamento where numDepto =" + numDepartamento);
            orden3.close();
            flag = true;
        } else {
            Statement orden4 = conn.createStatement();
            orden4.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM departamento where numDepto =" + numDepartamento);
            orden4.close();
            flag = true;
        }
        orden.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Esto es el main

```
case 3:
                    Departamento d1 = new Departamento();
                    int numero;
                    System.out.println("introduzca numero de departamento: ");
                    numero = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("introduzca nombre del nuevo departamento: ");
                    d1.setNombre(entrada.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("introduzca la direccion del nuevo departamento: ");
                    d1.setDireccion(entrada.nextLine());
                    System.out.println("introduzca numero de departamento nuevo: ");
                    d1.setNumDepartamento(Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine()));
                    if (base_datos.borrarDepartamento(d1, numero)) {
                        System.out.println("Departamento borrado de la base de datos...");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Departamento no encontrado en la base de datos...");
                    }
                    System.out.println("\nPresiona Intro para continuar....");
                    entrada.nextLine();
                    break;
```

Comment: El *select* sobra; si haces el *update* sí o sí, si no hay registros afectados simplemente no hará nada. Pero el problema grande es que debes asegurarte que entre el *update* y el *delete* nadie te introduzca un nuevo empleado, p.ej. con transacciones con los bloqueos adecuados.

Comment: Me he perdido que quiere decir lo de la transaccion de bloqueos. @SJuan76 el select es necesario porque si hay gente he de crear otro departamento y sino pues lo borro del tiron

Comment: Si el nuevo departamento es ficticio... ¿por qué lo creas siquiera? Permite valores *null* en el FK y cuando se borre un departamento que se pongan los valores del departamento a *null*.

Comment: Naturalmente, lo más normal es que simplemente dejes que el FK lance la excepción si quedan trabajadores en el departamento; usualmente no tiene sentido que haya trabajadores sin departamento. Lo habitual sería reasignar trabajadores a otros departamentos "a mano"(*), uno a uno, y solo poder borrar el departamento cuando no haya trabajadores. (*) Normalmente no borras departamentos más que muy de tanto en tanto, y en el caso excepcional en que todos los trabajadores de un departamento se asigne a otro, siempre puedes ejecutar el SQL por consola.

Comment: El problema es que eso no es lo que me piden. lo que me piden es borrar un departamento y si hay gente reasignarla @SJuan76. ademas yo no puedo tocar la tabla para que acepte valores nulos porque eso es cosa del profesor

Answer (score 1):

Me resulta un poco confuso como has hecho el código.

Entiendo que en la tabla "Personas", hay un campo llamado "numdepartamento" que apunta al PK de la tabla "Departamentos"

En este fragmento de código, si existen personas dentro del departamento que se va a eliminar, se hace lo siguiente:

- Creamos un departamento nuevo con los datos del departamento que le pasamos ( si "numDepartamento" es PK, aquí vas a tener un pete en BBDD)
- Actualizas los registros "Persona" que su campo "numDepartamento" sea igual al que se va a eliminar, y **lo seteas al mismo valor** (vamos, que no se actualiza por que se queda igual)
- Eliminas el departamento

  ```
  if (existe == true) {
          Statement orden1 = conn.createStatement();
          orden1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO departamento(Nombre, direccion, numdepartamento)  VALUES('"
                  + nombreD + "','" + direccion + "','" + numNDepartamento + "')");
          orden1.close();
          Statement orden2 = conn.createStatement();
          orden2.executeUpdate("UPDATE persona "
                  + "SET nombre = '" + numDepartamento + "',"
                  + "WHERE numdepartamento = " + numNDepartamento);
          orden2.close();
          Statement orden3 = conn.createStatement();
          orden3.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM departamento where numdepartamento =" + numDepartamento);
  }
  ```

A mi parecer, te has complicado mucho.

---

De primeras, no necesitas el primer select, tal y como te han dicho en los comentarios. Luego te sobra el crear de nuevo el mismo departamento. No tenia ningún sentido este fragmento de código.

Luego esta la actualización de las personas existentes a ese departamento. Si quieres que sea obligatorio que tengan un departamento o que el valor del campo no sea null, crea un departamento que llames "sin departamento" con id=0 (o el que tu quieras) y ejecutas esta query

```
orden2.executeUpdate("UPDATE persona "
  + "SET nombre = '" + <null o 0>+ "',"
  + "WHERE numdepartamento = " + numNDepartamento);
```

Con esto, te debería de bastar.

Échale un ojo a lo que te ha dicho SJuan76, ya que seria problemático que se añadiese una persona justo antes de eliminarse el departamento. Mira de crear una especie de semáforo para las transacciones con BBDD

Comment: el select es necesario porque es necesario saber si hay gente o no en el departamento y en funcion de eso se hace una cosa u otra. lo de Sjuan ya si que no se como hacerlo. mñn intentare ver el codigo a ver

Comment: es mas yo seteo un valor nadie a dicho que sea el mismo que ya tenia, es mas yo solo quiero cambiar el numero de departamento no el nombre

Comment: Si ninguna persona esta en el departamento a eliminar, el update no va a hacer nada, continua y termina al final haciendo el delete. Si hay personas en el departamento, el update los cambia, continua y al final hace el delete. Tu primer select, es un condicional de si se update+delete o solo delete; pero es q justamente el update que te he puesto hace eso.

Comment: Luego dices que solo quieres cambiar el numero del departamento, no el nombre. si, hice copy paste a tu codigo y me he dado cuenta que seteas el nombre (que no entiendo), seria mas bien así el update  `orden2.executeUpdate("UPDATE persona "  + "SET numNDepartamento = '" + <null o 0>+ "',"  + "WHERE numdepartamento = " + numNDepartamento);`

Comment: perdon ya corregi ese error antes ahroa esta como deberia

Comment: el metodo da null pointer. Pero no entiendo porque la consultas estan correctas ahora o eso parece

Comment: Indica en que parte del codigo da el nullPointer @carlosdiaz

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at tarea10.ConectorBD.borrarDepartamento(ConectorBD.java:97) esta es la linea del statemenet
 at tarea10.TareaUnidad10.main(TareaUnidad10.java:85) es la linea del if en el main
he puesto el codigo del main

Comment: Añade un `return false` despues del `System.out.println(e);` para que en caso de que pete una consulta, no devuelva null y devuelva false. Ahora tienes que averiguar que consulta falla @carlosdiaz

Comment: tengo un metodo que ayer en clase iba y hoy da null pointer algo raro pasa

Comment: ya le he puesto el flah flase en caso de que falle y sigue dando null. al ser el fallo en el estatement primero igual es cosa de la conexion pero no se he reiniciado y vuelto probar y sigue dando null pointer

Comment: Debugea, y averigua que falla. Estas teniendo un problema distinto del de la pregunta y no puedo seguir ayudandote por esta pregunta